# Calculate precision

Tags: php, number-formatting

Let's say I have a number `10.5`. Using PHP, I'd like to format it as `10.50`. I know I can use `number_format(10.5, 2)`. But the number of decimal places depends on a value `subunit_to_unit`, which in this case is equal to `100`. If all I know is that `subunit_to_unit` is `100`, how can I format `10.5` as `10.50`?

Comment: `printf('%.2f', $num)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logarithm of 100 to base 10 is 2. So you can just use [`log(subunit_to_unit, 10)`](http://php.net/log) to get your 2 here. You may want to floor the result, though, in case `subunit_to_unit` is something like 129.